# "Paul's neighbours were terrible so his brother's friends went round to have a word"

Tags: punctuation

I have the following sentence that i need to punctuate

> Paul's neighbours were terrible so his brother's friends went round
>   to have a word

From my knowledge a semicolon must be used between two independent clauses joined by coordinating conjunction;so this must be the punctuation:

> Paul's neighbours were terrible;so his brother's friends went round
>   to have a word

But [here](http://www.bristol.ac.uk/arts/exercises/grammar/grammar_tutorial/page_55.htm) in question 6 it says that a comma is needed before the coordinating conjunction hence the sentence is

> Paul's neighbours were terrible, so his brother's friends went round
>   to have a word.

Where am i wrong?

Comment: Those clauses aren't independent.

Comment: What's interesting is that the sentence would make more sense (and not be open to debate) if you simply swapped *terrible* and *so*: *Paul's neighbours were so terrible his brother's friends went round to have a word.*

Answer (score 1):

You are wrong that "a semicolon must be used between two independent clauses joined by a coordinating conjunction."

You should know that "two independent clauses can be joined by *either* a semicolon or a coordinating conjunction."

You should also be aware that it is somewhat odd for grammarians to teach that "a coordinating conjunction separates two independent clauses, but a subordinating conjunction changes the clause that it fronts into a dependent clause."  They do so because only a dependent clause is 'adverbial', which allows its position to change relative to the independent clause.